# What is inside a pointer on a modern x64 system?

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit

This code for example:

```
int x = 75;
int *p = &x;

printf("%llx\n",p);
```

Writes a 64-bit number.  What I'm asking is, what exactly is this number?  Yes, it is an address.

But is it an absolute address in virtual memory where the value 75 is stored?  Or is it possibly offset from some page marker, or an offset from the "start point" of the program's memory block?

If it matters, I'm asking about Windows 10, 64 bit, on a typical x64 intel chip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is the absolute address in your program's [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

It is not an offset.

In 16-bit Windows (which was common 30 years ago), a [segmented memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation) was used, in which pointers were segmented and consisted of a 16-bit segment pointer and a 16-bit offset (32 bits in total).

However, 32-bit and 64-bit Windows both use a [flat memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model), which uses absolute addresses.

Comment: You said "your program's virtual address space".  Can this mean that the same 64 bits in another program could point to another address in physical memory?  Or is it the case that it is globally unique to the specific physical location?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman It's virtually guaranteed that the same 64 bits in another program points to another address in physical memory (if it points to anything at all).

Comment: Then how does ReadProcessMemory work?  You give it a virtual address; does that mean it's based on the address space of the target process?

Comment: @WillihamTotland: In principle, you are correct. However, certain system DLLs, for example `kernel32.dll`, are always mapped to the same virtual addresses in every process. Also, it is not guaranteed that every virtual address is mapped to a physical address. Even valid virtual addresses are not necesarily mapped to physical addresses. For example, the contents of virtual addresses can be [paged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging) to disk, so that it doesn't even exist in memory.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: Yes, when calling `ReadProcessMemory`, you must also specify the target process. The address you pass to that function applies to the virtual address space of the target process.

Answer (score 1):

It is a virtual address, which is a virtual page number and an offset from the beginning of the page. The translation mechanism looks up in the page tables of the process to determine the corresponding physical page number and combines it with the offset to come up with the physical address.

Comment: Yes, you are right that when translating virtual addresses to physical addresses, a page table is used and that for purposes of this translation, the virtual memory address is divided into two parts: 1. an index into the page table and 2. a page offset. However, only the operating system (which maintains the page tables) must be aware of this technical detail. For a common programmer, it is not relevant (except maybe if you are writing a kernel driver). A common programmer will normally only see and care about the flat virtual address space of the process.